# C# How to use a Dictionary to reference other Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Based on what I have read elsewhere it appears the general advice is to use a Dictionary to dynamically access variable/objects and other dictionaries... however I seem to be missing something simple for the last case as I can not see how to get this to work. Basically I have multiple dictionaries of data and I wish to use the value in a variable to point to the appropriate dictionary and read its data:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// reference dictionary - pass LangID string to reference appropriate dictionary

public static Dictionary<string, dynamic> myDictionaries = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()

{

  { "EN", "EN_Dictionary" },

  { "FR", "FR_Dictionary" },

  { "DE", "DE_Dictionary" }

};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public static Dictionary<string, string> EN_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()

// EN language dictionary

{

  { "str1", "Some text in EN" },

  { "str2", "Some text in EN" },

  { "str3", "Some text in EN" }

};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public static Dictionary<string, string> FR_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()

// FR language dictionary

{

  { "str1", "Some text in FR" },

  { "str2", "Some text in FR" },

  { "str3", "Some text in FR" }

};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public static Dictionary<string, string> DE_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()

// DE language dictionary

{

  { "str1", "Some text in DE" },

  { "str2", "Some text in DE" },

  { "str3", "Some text in DE" }

};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

LangID = "DE";
```

//... but now what do I do ???

Comment: There's no need to have two level nesting here if you have disjoint keys. E.g. `DEstr1` and `FRstr1` etc - key is a concatenation of two strings - a language code and an actual key.

Comment: Change the order. Define the dictionary of dictionary as a last thing. Then you will be in a position to reference already definied dictionary and the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed dynamic to the actual definition of the language dictionaries and then added the variables not strings.

```
    // reference dictionary - pass LangID string to reference appropriate dictionary
    public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionaries = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
    {
        { "EN", EN_Dictionary },
        { "FR", FR_Dictionary },
        { "DE", DE_Dictionary }
    };

    public static Dictionary<string, string> EN_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "str1", "Some text in EN" },
        { "str2", "Some text in EN" },
        { "str3", "Some text in EN" }
    };

    public static Dictionary<string, string> FR_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    // FR language dictionary
    {
        { "str1", "Some text in FR" },
        { "str2", "Some text in FR" },
        { "str3", "Some text in FR" }
    };

    public static Dictionary<string, string> DE_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    // DE language dictionary
    {
        { "str1", "Some text in DE" },
        { "str2", "Some text in DE" },
        { "str3", "Some text in DE" }
    };
```

To use your reference dictionary...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string LangID = "DE";
        Dictionary<string, string> GermanDictionary = myDictionaries[LangID];
        string PhraseID = "str2";
        string GermanPhrase = GermanDictionary[PhraseID];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - this all helps a lot.

Answer (score 8):

are you asking how to access the dictionaries?  It would be as follows:

```
var text = myDictionaries["EN"]["str1"];
```

And you need to define your dictionaries like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> EN_Dictionary = ...etc;
public static Dictionary<string, string> FR_Dictionary  = ...etc;
public static Dictionary<string, string> DE_Dictionary = ...etc;
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDictionaries 
    = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
    {
        { "EN", EN_Dictionary },
        { "FR", FR_Dictionary },
        { "DE", DE_Dictionary }
    };
```

Comment: Thx for the feedback - here comes the "but" question - what if I want to pass the dictionary name as a reference to another section of code; how could I use this to dynaically provide a reference to the language dictionary ?

Comment: i'm not really sure what you mean by dynamically in this case.  May be best to create another question

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary of dictionaries. Example:

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>
```

Type of the keys and data may vary as per your need.